# Using a Service globally in a .module file

Tags: 8

I want to use a Service globally in a Drupal 8 .module file.
The service' name Manager.

in my_module.module I want to able to:

```
function some_function() {
  $data = $manager->someMethod();
}
```

i.s.o

```
function some_function() {
/** @var \Drupal\my_module\ManagerInterface */

  $manager = \Drupal::service('my_module.manager');
  $data = $manager->someMethod();
}
```

I know how to do it in a controller using $this. But because the code depends heavily on Drupal hooks, I have to access the Manager (many times) from within the .module file.

I have seen this: [Making an instantiated object in a module global](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95129/making-an-instantiated-object-in-a-module-global) but it refers to Drupal 7

EDIT:
After getting some the basics of D8 and OOP I realize now that what I was trying to do here is to dependency inject the service my_module.manager into the my_module.module file, which is not possible.
Good reason to refactor the code as much as possible into Classes.

Comment: The above should work. I've accessed services from hooks many times.

Comment: Though, you should rename your manager class to represent it's function.

Comment: Thanks @Eyal. I know it works. I was just looking for a more elegant sollution, but know I think this is elegant enough.